# How to "compileOnly" my android repository from github

Tags: android, maven, gradle, github, jitpack

I'm implementing my android-module from [github](https://github.com) using [jitpack](https://jitpack.io),
and i want to do `compileOnly` instead of `implementation`

but when I use the code `compileOnly` it shows me
that the `complieOnly` not supported

---

I'm creating an application to read plugins

all application and plugins depends on a library I have created

the plugin well have a classes that `extends` a class on the library
and the application should read those classes and `invoke` methods on them

as you know the application SHOULD contains the library `classes`
and the plugin SHOULDN'T, else we'll face a `doublecated classes exception` or/and `class cast exception`

I worked on it and it worked perfectly while the application and 
the plugins all `compiled` the library using an `aar` file of it

but when i decied to move on to [github](https://github.com) `implementation`
it worked for the application but not for the plugin
and the issue is i can't tell gradle to do `compileOnly` to the library

---

plugin's `module` `build.gradle` :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'com.github.LSaferSE:Services-Android:master'//<--- here is the problem

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha02'
}
```

plugin's `project` `build.gradle` :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

expecting a `build success` but faced :

```
ERROR: Android dependency 'com.github.LSaferSE:Services-Android:master' is set to compileOnly/provided which is not supported
```

---

one more thing, I tried using `api` instead but I'm not sure what's the diffrent from `implementation`, but I'm sure it'll pack library `classes` in the plugin's `apk`, so please tell me if you know it'll not effect while loading the `apk` using `DexClassLoader` (fyi it'll effect using `implementation`)

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `compileOnly` with `provided`. As per dependency [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies), the `compileOnly` behaves just like `provided` (which is now deprecated), but you might have been using the older version of build tool.

Comment: yeah I tried, but i got a deperecation warning :)

Comment: also this error (the same error) `Android dependency 'com.github.LSaferSE:Services-Android:master' is set to compileOnly/provided which is not supported`

Comment: at the moment I'm using internal aar file and it's working good, but the problem is javadoc well not be included while writing the code.